# Injecting dependencies for SignalR Hubs using autofac in in MVC 5 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, signalr, autofac, signalr-hub

I'm trying to bring SignalR 2 into an existing project in which all dependency injection is performed using autofac and all dependency configuration is performed in Global.asax.  I found the Autofac.SignalR package for using SignalR with autofac and its [accompanying documentation](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/SignalRIntegration).

I followed the example in the provided documentation and followed the suggestion of using the RegisterHubs function rather than defining my individual hub dependencies.

Unfortunately my Hub class gets the following run-time error when trying to resolve a dependency from the lifetimeScope

```
Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException was unhandled by user code
HResult=-2146233088
Message=No scope with a Tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is
visible from the scope in which instance was requested.
This generally indicates that a component registered as per-HTTP
request is being requested by a SingleInstance() component
(or a similar scenario.) Under the web integration always request
dependencies from the DependencyResolver.Current or 
ILifetimeScopeProvider.RequestLifetime, never from the container itself.
```

I haven't been able to get DependencyResolver.Current or ILifeTimeScopeProvider to work for me.

My dependency config is as follows

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    .RegisterControllers(typeof (MvcApplication).Assembly);
    .RegisterHubs(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    ...
var container = builder.Build();

// Set dependency resolver for MVC
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));

// Set dependency resolver for Web API
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

// Set the dependency resolver for SignalR
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));

var signalRDependencyResolver = new Autofac.Integration.SignalR.AutofacDependencyResolver(container);
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = signalRDependencyResolver;
```

I also set up my hub class according to the example:

```
public class BaseHub : Hub
{
    protected readonly ILifetimeScope _hubLifetimeScope;
    private static IUserSignalRConnectionRepository _userSignalRConnectionRepository;

    public BaseHub(ILifetimeScope lifetimeScope) : base()
    {
        _hubLifetimeScope = lifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope();

        _userSignalRConnectionRepository = _hubLifetimeScope.Resolve<IUserSignalRConnectionRepository>();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        // Dipose the hub lifetime scope when the hub is disposed.
        if (disposing && _hubLifetimeScope != null)
            _hubLifetimeScope.Dispose();

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

The exception occurs in the cub class on the line

```
_userSignalRConnectionRepository = _hubLifetimeScope.Resolve<IUserSignalRConnectionRepository>();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should include the code where you are registering your IUserSignalRConnectionRepository.

The error message seems to indicate that this dependency was registered using `InstancePerHttpRequest()` which equivalent to `InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope("AutofacWebRequest")`. This scope is created automatically for you in the case of MVC requests, but not for SignalR requests (which is probably a good thing since they can last indefinitely).

You can probably work around this by calling `lifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope("AutofacWebRequest");`. instead of `lifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope();` in your Hub constructor.

Alternatively, you could register IUserSignalRConnectionRepository using `InstancePerDependency()` (which is the default) or `SingleInstance()` instead of `InstancePerHttpRequest()`.

Comment: Thank you.  You are correct that IUserSignalRConnectionRepository is being registered as InstancePerHttpRequest() in a batch with the rest of our repositories.

Your workaround of using lifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope("AutofacWebRequest"); appears to work.

Would there be an advantage to registering my repository interface as InstancePerDependency() or SingleInstance() instead of using the workaround?

I have some dependencies that I will want to reference from hubs as well as MVC classes so it would be ideal if I can do one registration that works for both.

Comment: I think it's fine to use InstancePerHttpRequest() and then using lifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope("AutofacWebRequest"). I don't think this will be any different that using InstancePerDependency() since it is only resolved once per scope. I should add that SignalR instantiates a new hub for each invocation which does not correspond 1-to-1 with web requests. In the case of WebSockets, a single request is responsible for many invocations. I don't think this really matters unless your IUserSignalRConnectionRepository depends on being created once per actual request.

Comment: Nope, instantiating IUserSignalRConnectionRepository as infrequently as possible is ideal.  It's part of the custom SignalR backplane I need to build to keep track of user SignalR connections across our load balanced server farm using our MongoDB data repository, so that should work out just fine. I will keep my eye on garbage collection though just to be sure everything gets cleaned up properly. That dependency itself will probably be refactored out, but I will have similar dependencies for some of my hubs.

Comment: If you are trying to instantiate IUserSignalRConnectionRepository as infrequently as possible, you might want to register it using SingleInstance(). This will cause IUserSignalRConnectionRepository to be instantiated once for the entire lifetime of you app the first time it is resolved. Any time it is resolved afterwords, the original instance will be returned. If you do this, your Hub code doesn't need to change to call lifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope("AutofacWebRequest").